# PERL DBI - Inserting While Reading File Via Regular EXP

Tags: sql, perl, insert, dbi

I Have a very god Knowledge of SQL (Oracle) but just lately I am trying to make it co-operate with PERL;

reason is queit obvious i am reading log files of thousand of rows  and cleaning them with a REGXP;

While cleaning them I want to Insert into a Table (already existing in my Server) - but i am struggling with syntax and quotes;

example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;

my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:Oracle:DB1", "test", "test")
or die "Couldnt connect to database: $DBI::errstr";

my $file = 'C:\Users\log.txt';
open my $fh, "<", $file or die "Could not open $file: $!";

......
......
.....
....
......

##THIS PRINTS ABSOLUTELY FINE

 printf('$datetime_event=%s; $logonid=%s; $clientid=%s; $cliet_user_id=%s; $ip=%s; $duration=%s; $class_path=%s', @fields);
    print "\n";

## THIS IS THE INSERT THAT IS NOT WORKING

    my $sth = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO REQUEST (REQUEST_ID,DATETIME_EVENT, LOGONID, CLIENTID,USERID, DURATION,IP,METHOD)
    Values (REQUEST_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL,TO_DATE(SUBSTR($datetime_event ,0,19), "YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS"),$logonid,$clientid,$cliet_user_id,$duration, $ip,$class_path');
    #or die "Couldn't execute statement: " . $sth->errstr;

    # Execute the SQL statement; don't print it yet
    $sth->execute or warn 'Execute failed: ' . $dbh->errstr;

    # This "loop" prints all the rows (actually just one, in this case)
    while (my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array) {
    print "@row\n";
}



}


# gracefully disconnect from the database
$dbh->disconnect();
```

errors:

```
DBD::Oracle::st execute failed: ORA-00911: invalid character (DBD ERROR: error possibly near <*> indicator at char 141 in 'INSERT INTO REQUEST (REQUEST_ID,DATETIME_EVENT, LOGONID, CLIENTID,USERID, DURATION,IP,METHOD)
    Values (REQUEST_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL,TO_DATE(SUBSTR(<*>$datetime_event ,0,19), "YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS"),$logonid,$clientid,$cliet_user_id,$duration, $ip,$class_path') [for Statement "INSERT INTO REQUEST (REQUEST_ID,DATETIME_EVENT, LOGONID, CLIENTID,USERID, DURATION,IP,METHOD)
    Values (REQUEST_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL,TO_DATE(SUBSTR($datetime_event ,0,19), "YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS"),$logonid,$clientid,$cliet_user_id,$duration, $ip,$class_path"] at D:/PERL/Log/CleanFileV1.pl line 42, <$fh> line 1.
Execute failed: ORA-00911: invalid character (DBD ERROR: error possibly near <*> indicator at char 141 in 'INSERT INTO REQUEST (REQUEST_ID,DATETIME_EVENT, LOGONID, CLIENTID,USERID, DURATION,IP,METHOD)
    Values (REQUEST_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL,TO_DATE(SUBSTR(<*>$datetime_event ,0,19), "YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS"),$logonid,$clientid,$cliet_user_id,$duration, $ip,$class_path') at D:/PERL/Log/CleanFileV1.pl line 42, <$fh> line 1.
```

Updated

```
my ( $datetime_event, $logonid, $clientid, $cliet_user_id,$duration, $ip, $class_path ) = @fields;


    # Execute the SQL statement; don't print it yet
    my $sth = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO REQUEST (REQUEST_ID, DATETIME_EVENT, LOGONID, CLIENTID, USERID, DURATION, IP, METHOD)
    VALUES (REQUEST_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL, TO_DATE(SUBSTR(?, 0, 19), "YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS"), ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)')
    or die "Couldn't execute statement: " . $sth->errstr;

    $sth->execute( $datetime_event, $logonid, $clientid, $cliet_user_id,$duration, $ip, $class_path )
    or warn 'Execute failed: ' . $dbh->errstr;

}

# gracefully disconnect from the database
$dbh->disconnect();
```

NEW ERRORS:

```
DBD::Oracle::st execute failed: ORA-00984: column not allowed here (DBD ERROR: error possibly near <*> indicator at char 159 in 'INSERT INTO REQUEST (REQUEST_ID, DATETIME_EVENT, LOGONID, CLIENTID, USERID, DURATION, IP, METHOD)
    VALUES (REQUEST_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL, TO_DATE(SUBSTR(:p1, 0, 19), <*>"YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS"), :p2, :p3, :p4, :p5, :p6, :p7)') [for Statement "INSERT INTO REQUEST (REQUEST_ID, DATETIME_EVENT, LOGONID, CLIENTID, USERID, DURATION, IP, METHOD)
    VALUES (REQUEST_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL, TO_DATE(SUBSTR(?, 0, 19), "YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS"), ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)" with ParamValues: :p1='2014-09-21 00:09:22,718', :p2='admin12', :p3='895', :p4='258', :p5='111.1.1.1', :p6='0.023', :p7='Calculate.LoanExmple'] at D:/PERL/Log/CleanFileV1.pl line 43, <$fh> line 6.
Execute failed: ORA-00984: column not allowed here (DBD ERROR: error possibly near <*> indicator at char 159 in 'INSERT INTO REQUEST (REQUEST_ID, DATETIME_EVENT, LOGONID, CLIENTID, USERID, DURATION, IP, METHOD)
    VALUES (REQUEST_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL, TO_DATE(SUBSTR(:p1, 0, 19), <*>"YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS"), :p2, :p3, :p4, :p5, :p6, :p7)') at D:/PERL/Log/CleanFileV1.pl line 43, <$fh> line 6.
```

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL statement is surrounded by single quotes, so none of your `$variables` will be interpolated.

You'd do better to replace them with `?`s and then pass the variables to `execute` to let the database driver do the work:

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare(
    'INSERT INTO REQUEST (
        REQUEST_ID, DATETIME_EVENT, LOGONID, CLIENTID, USERID, DURATION, IP, METHOD
    ) VALUES (
        REQUEST_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL, TO_DATE(SUBSTR(?, 0, 19), "YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS"), ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?
    )'
) or die "Couldn't execute statement: " . $sth->errstr;

# Execute the SQL statement; don't print it yet
$sth->execute(
    $datetime_event, $logonid, $clientid, $cliet_user_id, $duration, $ip, $class_path
) or warn 'Execute failed: ' . $dbh->errstr;
```

Comment: is telling me sth requires a package name also all the variables too;

Comment: Are you declaring them with `my`?

Comment: You're missing a closing quote on the `DBI->connect` line, and do something to assign the contents of `@fields` to those individual variables: `my ($datetime_id, $logonid, ...) = @fields`

Comment: Global symbol "$sth" requires explicit package name
A fatal error (trappable)
You've said "use strict vars", which indicates that all variables
must either be lexically scoped (using "my"), declared beforehand using
"our", or explicitly qualified to say which package the global variable
is in (using "::").

Comment: You're still missing the closing quote which could be throwing everything else off.

Comment: i am a dummy, completely, i am using perl fpr the first time and i think maybe jump to sql insert is silly for me? i have done similar thing in .sh but i do not quiet understand you Jim; closing quote missing in the first line? where shall i declare this variable my ($datetime_id, $logonid, ...) = @fields ?

Comment: Look at the syntax highlighting in your updated code.  The last argument to `DBI->connect` is missing a closing quote.

Comment: sorry was badly copied in Eclipse is ok; the error when i compile is in line 40 : Global symbol "$sth" requires explicit package name it is looking like i am missing something; also i have declared those varialbes against the fields is that location correct or the way i have done it?

Comment: looks better i have removed use strict; and those variable declaration is not giving me compiling errors i just get the error added in main post NEW ERRORS

Comment: eUREKAAAAAAAAA.....was Oracle error-- a date value into a varchar- changed an all is perfect thanks budddyyyyyy